# how to open sharepoint site in Visual Studio for developing

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a new sharepoint 2013 site through Central admin. Now how do I open this site (file) in visual studio, because I have to create pagelayouts and content types in visual studio. Please help.

Comment: If you need any further help ,please let me know

Comment: Could you share any tutorials for creating page layouts and content types in visual studio? THanks

Comment: Link for [Page Layout](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/182458/how-to-create-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-st.aspx)
[Content Type(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/410880/SharePoint-Creating-a-Custom-Content-Type-usi)
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SharePoint site cannot be opened in Visual Studio. You can develop features in Visual Studio and deploy them through Visual Studio on a SharePoint site which is later activated and used.

If you are using Visual Studio 2012 then I believe you will have to get [Office Tools for VS2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=257068) to start your development.

And if you VS2013 then I guess they are already there

[How and where to start developing SharePoint 2013 projects in Visual Studio 2012](http://www.ashokraja.me/articles/How-to-create-a-new-Visual-WebPart-in-SharePoint-2013-with-Visual-Studio-2012) is a nice start to read

An ideal approach for you would be:

1. Create a SharePoint empty project using Visual Studio
2. Add modules in it for `Page Layouts` and `Content Types`
3. Create a `Package`.
4. This `Package` should be deployed on SharePoint Site and activating it will give all the page layouts and content type on your site.

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the ideal approach... It does make sense.... hence could you please tell me how do I create Page Layouts, content types and package in visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

You don't open SharePoint sites in the same way you open an ASP.NET website. Getting started with SharePoint development is not as easy as getting started with ASP.NET.

This video, [SharePoint for ASP.NET Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=an1IkFzHpBk), will not answer your question but it will give you a foundation you can use as a basis for further learning.

I highly recommend that you also consider getting a book or two, getting some online training or attending in-person training. I have recommendations for all of these if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open sites directly in Visual Studio for Editing.

But in case you want to edit any particular file. Go to site contents > Any Library (not list) and try the "Open With Explorer" option

[image]

You can edit any 
1. Masterpage
2. Site Page
3. CSS HTML JS 
Files. Hope this solves your query